# Rust: Formatting a formatted string

Tags: rust, formatting

To print a string *centered* by 15 dashes, i'd do the following:

```
println!("{:-^15}", "Hi :D");
```

But what if i wanted to control the number of dashes that are put before and after my string? I tried the following:

```
let margin: usize = 15;
println!("{:-^{margin}}", "Hi :(");
```

And other variations, but all of them don't compile. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had the syntax of [formatting parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-parameters).  Here are a few ways to use them:

```
println!("{:-^1$}", "Hi :D", 15);
let margin = 15;
println!("{:-^1$}", "Hi :D", margin);
println!("{:-^margin$}", "Hi :D");
```